# spring redis increment

Tags: spring, redis

i want to substitute memcached for spring-redis.

memcached has function

```
         *  @param key         key
         * @param delta
         *            increment delta
         * @param initValue
         *            the initial value to be added when value is not found
         * @param timeout
         *            operation timeout
         * @param exp
         *            the initial vlaue expire time, in seconds. Can be up to 30
         *            days. After 30 days, is treated as a unix timestamp of an
         *            exact date.
         * @return
         * @throws TimeoutException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         * @throws MemcachedException
         */
        long incr(String key, long delta, long initValue, long timeout, int exp)
                throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, MemcachedException;
```

spring-redis has function

```
Long increment(K key, long delta);
```

how can i set operation timeout(not expire) in spring-redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spring-redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) doesnt allow you to configure timeout per individual request (as in memcached realization). You can configure timeout per connection with a configuration setting in application.properties:

> spring.redis.timeout=5000

Comment: Accept answer if like it :)